# Modsecurity on Nginx modsecurity.conf-recommended Source Not Found

Tags: nginx

I want to install Modsecurity on Nginx with using this document :

https://www.nginx.com/blog/compiling-and-installing-modsecurity-for-open-source-nginx/

I installed and compiled it. But when I want to try this command it fails. Because source is not found :

```
wget -P /etc/nginx/modsec/ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/master/modsecurity.conf-recommended
```

So if you try yourself to access this link, you will see 404 Not Found error on the page :

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/master/modsecurity.conf-recommended

Is there any other source link to download modsecurity.conf-recommended file for Nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it in the original [repository on github](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity):

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/v2/master/modsecurity.conf-recommended
```